# How to sort the whole display table

Tags: jsp, jakarta-ee, displaytag

i have 200 records and i am displaying the data in dispaly table 50 per page , i put some column as sortable as true .

but its sorting only that page(50) records only not the whole 200 records ?

How can i sort the whole records.

Answer (score 1):

See http://www.displaytag.org/1.2/configuration.html:

> sort.amount : Indicates if the full list should be sorted before
>   paging or if the sorting only affects items in the current page.
>   Default behaviour is to sort only items in the current page (first
>   paging, then sorting)

You may change this configuration for the whole webapp (by setting its value in the displaytag.properties file), or you may change it for a specific table using the `<display:setProperty>` tag.